# ListView with CursorAdapter does not display my values

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to display some of the contents of my database to the user with a scroll ability.

So I have extended the ListActivity and I used the SimpleCursorAdapter. The problem is that i can not see the values displaced.

```
private void fillData() {
 // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
ListData = data.findAllDbValues();
startManagingCursor(ListData);

// Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list
String[] from = new String[]{Data.ID, Data.DESC};

// and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to 
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

// Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display 
ListAdapter la = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, ListData, from, to);//R.layout.showdata
setListAdapter(la);

}
```

If I use a custom layout(R.layout.showdata),where it has only two TextViews, I can see the values but I have to touch the text which is displayed to do my job instead of just touching anywhere of the selection.

So I want to use a simple_list_item_2 so I can have this ability. Any ideas why I do not see the values or how can I make my custom layout to produce the same abilities with the simple_list?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You say you can't see the values. Then you say you can see them but can only click the individual TextViews?

Comment: I mean that if I use the custom layout i can see my values but i have to click on the text to have result and not everywhere in the selection. Also if i use the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 i don't see any value..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android_orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="4dip"
android:paddingRight="5dp">
<TextView android:id="@+id/productRow"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The trick is to wrap the `TextView` row in a `LinearLayout`.  This lets me click anywhere on the list element to select it.

Comment: Did you surround both custom TextViews with LinearLayouts that have "fill_parent" values?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I arrived here through Google and I think I have the answer since I had similar problem.

You are referencing custom `TextView` in your `int[] to` array, not the Android ones. You must use instead:

```
// and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to 
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
```

Just check out that the ids in the XML and the ids in your class are the same. When you use custom views the reference in your class is 
`R.id.text1` and in your layout `android:id="@+id:text1"` but when you use Android resources the reference in your class is `android.R.id.text1` and in your layout `android:id="@android:id/text1"`.

You can use any of them but it must be consistent.

I was using `android:id="@+id:text1"` in my XML (creating a new TextView with id "text1") but using `android.R.id.text1` in my Java Class so the `CursorAdaptor` was setting the information in a non-existent View and I was getting exactly that result: a listview with all the rows without text.